# Grep -f only returns full input file

Tags: grep

I need to isolate specific genes from the CARD database (basically fasta files). I created a list of gene names of interest to use

```
grep -wA1 -f list.file database.file
```

(A1 to get the respective sequence as well)

The problem is, that even though the command is correctly identifying the genes of interest, the output is still the complete database.file just with the search patterns marked. That is of course not helping too much...

Does someone know what I do wrong? I know, that the problem is solvable by loops, but I think the -f option would be exactly what I need, plus it used to work nicely.

Comment: "it used to work nicely" -- when? how?

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), we need to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help you.

Comment: I was using the  -w -f options on other data-sets in the past and there it worked nicely

Comment: seems that the whole file matches. How many lines is `database.file`? Also it would be helpful to add some data, both files if possible.

Comment: Have you maybe got a blank line in your `list.file`?

Comment: What @MarkSetchell said.  `grep '' database.file` is equivalent to `cat database.file`.  The empty regex matches every line, so you have to avoid empty lines in your `list.file`